# use regex in within Selector

Tags: javascript, regex, selector

Here is an array:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#header-links li a')

[<a href=​"https:​/​/​www.example.com/​en/​newsstand/​">​Magazines​</a>​, <a href=​"https:​/​/​secure.indas.on.com/​example/​promo/​GiveAGift/​">​Gifts​</a>​, <a href=​"https:​/​/​www.example.com/​fr/​">​Français​</a>​]
```

The order of these elements may change but I'd like to grab the textContent of the element whose href ends in `en/` or `fr/`. There will never be a case of both appearing on the same page (They are language alternation links).

```
document.querySelectorAll('#header-links li a[href*="fr"')[0].textContent.trim();
Français
```

Works for French. The same works for English.

How can I make my selector work for either `en` or `fr`?

```
document.querySelectorAll('#header-links li a[href*="/(fr|en)/"')[0].textContent.trim();
```

Comment: If you want to match something whose `href` ends in `en/`, you want `[href$="en/"]`, not `[href*="en"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I make my selector work for either en or fr?

you should use `,`.

```
document.querySelectorAll('#header-links li a[href*="fr"],#header-links li a[href*="en"]')...
```